# How to efficiently enumerating all perfect squares?

Tags: python, performance, math

I have made the following program which asks for a user input upper bound and calculates & prints every perfect square up to the upper bound. However, I think that my `is_perfect_square` function is not very efficient as it takes a long time to compute the perfect squares when the upper bound is in the thousands or more. I am wondering how I can make my program more efficient, I think using the math module with to use `sqrt` could work but I am no mathematician so request help.
My program is:

```
"""Print all the perfect squares from zero up to a given maximum."""
import math

def read_bound():
   """Reads the upper bound from the standard input (keyboard).
      If the user enters something that is not a positive integer
      the function issues an error message and retries
      repeatedly"""
   upper_bound = None
   while upper_bound is None:
       line = input("Enter the upper bound: ")
       if line.isnumeric() and int(line) >= 0:
           upper_bound = int(line)
           return upper_bound
       else:
           print("You must enter a positive number.")



def is_perfect_square(num):
   """Return true if and only if num is a perfect square"""
   for candidate in range(1, num):
       if candidate * candidate == num:
           return True



def print_squares(upper_bound, squares):
   """Print a given list of all the squares up to a given upper bound"""


   print("The perfect squares up to {} are: ". format(upper_bound))
   for square in squares:
       print(square, end=' ')



def main():
   """Calling the functions"""
   upper_bound = read_bound()
   squares = []
   for num in range(2, upper_bound + 1):
       if is_perfect_square(num):
           squares.append(num)

   print_squares(upper_bound, squares)


main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `sqrt`

```
import math
def is_perfect_square(num):
   """Return true if and only if num is a perfect square"""
    root = math.sqrt(num)
    return int(root) - root == 0
```

or as @PacoH showed:

```
    return root.is_integer()
```

Comment: This only reduces the runtime to `O(upper_bound)` while `O(sqrt(upper-bound))` is achievable.

Answer (score 3):

I would completely reverse the logic by first taking the square root of your upper bound, then printing the square of each positive integer lesser or equal that number:

```
upper_bound = int(input('Enter the upper bound: '))

upper_square_root = int(upper_bound**(1/2))

print([i**2 for i in range (1, upper_square_root+1)])
```

Example output for bound 78:

> [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64]

This way you avoid A LOT of unnecessary loops and math calculations.

Answer (score 2):

As you said using `math.sqrt`:

```
import math


def is_perfect_square(num):
    """Return true if and only if num is a perfect square"""
    return math.sqrt(num).is_integer()
```

Answer (score 2):

Squares are the partial sums of the odd numbers:

```
 1 = 1
 4 = 1 + 3
 9 = 1 + 3 + 5
16 = 1 + 3 + 5 + 7
```

So you can simply do this:

```
   square = 1
   odd = 1
   while square <= upper_bound:
    print(square)
    odd = odd + 2
    square = square + odd
```

https://ideone.com/dcnEVJ

No need for square root or checking each number. It doesn't get much faster than this.